# How can access the angular js app from outside the app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have one angular js app and I want to access the function or file of this app from outside the angular app structure which is not even located in same angular structure using angular js, javascript or jQuery. Is it possible or not?

What is another best way for this?

I already tried by making one separate file in the angular app and I call the one function of this file from outside the app but I am unable to access the angular js function from this file. I am trying accessing this file from the regular js file which is located outside the app.

Comment: `var myAppRootscope = null; app.run(function($rootScope) { myAppRootscope = $rootScope; })`. And now you can use myAppRootscope from outside. You can do that for the service of your choice

Comment: Have you tried what I commented ? `app` is your `angular.module('MyModule').`